# Convert timezone format in Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

I need to convert below timezone format in the following format:

**Input**:
2020-10-28T20:12:20.986Z

**Output**:
28-OCT-20 8:12 PM

I tried below query but I am unable to get timestamp with it. Please help.

`select TO_TIMESTAMP(SUBSTR('2020-04-21T13:02:31.259Z',1,(INSTR('2020-04-21T13:02:31.259Z', 'T') - 1)),'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') from dual;`

Comment: the input is a timestamp or a varchar2 column ?

Comment: `select TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('2020-04-21T13:02:31.259Z','YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF"Z"') from dual;`?

Comment: `timestamp/date` datatype have no format. They are stored as a *value* (in internal format, of course) that may be displayed by the client application according to the cultural settings. If you want to convert it to string in the query (which is not a good design, because data display is a task for frontend app), then use explicit `to_char`.

Answer (score 2):

One option might be this

```
SQL>  alter session set nls_timestamp_format = 'dd-MON-YY hh:mi PM' ;

Session altered.

SQL> select to_timestamp('2020-10-28T20:12:20.986Z','yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh24:mi:ss.ff3"Z"') from dual ;

TO_TIMESTAMP('2020-10-28T20:12:20.986Z','YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF3"Z"')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
28-OCT-20 08:12 PM

SQL>
```

But if you rely better in the `to_timestamp` function without any session setting, then it is better

```
SQL>  select to_timestamp('2020-10-28T20:12:20.986Z','yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh24:mi:ss.ff3"Z"') from dual ;

TO_TIMESTAMP('2020-10-28T20:12:20.986Z','YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF3"Z"')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
28-OCT-20 08.12.20.986000000 PM
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a timestamp string with a time zone, use `TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ` rather than `TO_TIMESTAMP` and then use `TO_CHAR` to format it:

```sql
SELECT TO_CHAR(
         TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ(
           '2020-04-21T13:02:31.259Z',
           'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FFTZR'
         ),
         'DD-MON-RR HH12:MI AM',
         'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=American'
       )
FROM   DUAL;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=9249dc0d140c09b82772b5fbced2abb7)*

---

*Note: `DATE`, `TIMESTAMP` and `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` are binary data types and are stored in 7-20 bytes (1 byte each for century, year-of-century, month, day, hour, minute and second then up to 6 optional bytes for fractional seconds for `TIMESTAMP`s and up to 7-bytes for time zone for `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`). It is never stored in any particular format.*

*How the `DATE`/`TIMESTAMP` data types are displayed is dependent on the client application that you are using to query the database; some may use the NLS settings for the user's session but others do not use that. If you want a particular format then convert the `DATE`/`TIMESTAMP` to a string using `TO_CHAR`.*